# C const void * param from Swift: Data?.withUnsafeBytes and UnsafeRawPointer

Tags: c, swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to pass the bytes contained within a `Data?` to a C function. The C function is declared like:

```
void func(const void *buffer);
```

And my Swift looks like:

```
myData?.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer: UnsafeRawPointer) in
    func(buffer)
}
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '_'
```

If I change `UnsafeRawPointer` to `UnsafePointer<Void>`, then the code builds, but I get a warning:

```
UnsafePointer<Void> has been replaced by UnsafeRawPointer
```

What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can pass *any* data pointer to a C function taking a
`void *` argument, the problem can be solved with

```
myData?.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer: UnsafePointer<Int8>)  in
    myfunc(buffer)
}
```

Alternatively you can just omit the type annotation and let the
compiler infer the type automatically:

```
myData?.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer)  in
    myfunc(buffer)
}
```

or

```
myData?.withUnsafeBytes {
    myfunc($0)
}
```

Interestingly, the type is inferred as `UnsafePointer<Void>`, without
any warning.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, and I should have tried it myself

Comment: @MartinR Congrats on 300k :)

Comment: @craig65535: There is a simpler solution, see update.